# ExtJS 4 - Show LoadMask without spinner image

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4.2, loadmask

This should probably be pretty straighforward but I haven't been able to figure it out.  I'm just trying to show a loadmask on a component without the spinner image.  Everything else I want to look exactly the same.

I've set up a jsfiddle with a regular loadmask applied.  Again, just trying to figure out how to exclude the spinner image.

```
  Ext.onReady(function () {
      Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
          height: 500,
          width: 500,
          autoShow: true,
          title: 'Loadmask example',
          html: 'adsfa',
          listeners: {
              boxready: function (win) {
                  var lm = new Ext.LoadMask(win, {
                      msg: 'loadmask msg'
                  });
                  lm.show();
              }
          }
      });
  });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5v6pqwaL/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a custom css class to the `LoadMask` object. You need to override background of this class.

```
.custom-mask .x-mask-msg-text {
    background: transparent !important;
    padding: 5px !important
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cuywsdhw/)

Comment: Thanks.  However, at times I still need to be able to use the default loadmask with the spinner.  Is there a way to apply a css class like yours to just an individual loadmask?